# Flatten a folder structure to a file name in Bash

Tags: bash, find, sed

I'm trying to convert files from this structure:

```
foldera/folderb/filec.png
```

to:

```
foldera_folderb_filec.png
```

I'm halfway there:

```
 find . -type f -name "*.png" | sed 's@^./@@g;s@/@-@g'
```

which basically converts the name structure. However, it doesn't do the copy yet. At this point I'm stuck. How can I expand on the script to actually perform the copy operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
find . -type f -name "*.png" | sed 'h;y/\//_/;H;g;s/\n/ /g;s/^/cp -v /' | sh
```

Comment: wow.great. This basically works, except that all files start with '._'

Answer (score 4):

This worked well for me. It eliminates the ._ prefix, but is otherwise the same as [potong's answer](https://superuser.com/a/397666/291415).

```
find . -type f -name "*" | sed 's/$/"/;s/^/"/;h;s/^...//;s/^/"/;y/\//_/;H;g;s/\n/ /g;s/^/cp -v /' | sh
```

Answer (score 3):

```
find -type f -name '*.png' -printf '%P\0' | \
while read -d $'\0' i ; do cp "$i" "${i////_}" ; done
```

#### Where:

- `%P` tell `find` to omit the leading `./`;
- `\0` tell `find` to print the paths using the `ASCII NUL` character as separator (this should avoid problems with *strange* names);
- `-d $'\0'` tell `bash` to use the proper delimiter for reading the paths;
- `${i////_}` tell `bash` to replace every occurrences of `/` with `_` in the path.

#### Warning:

This pipeline may involve file overwrites, make sure to take the proper precautions.

Comment: find: illegal option -- t. find: illegal option -- y. find: illegal option -- p. find: illegal option -- e. find: -printf: unknown option  =(   Should I have told you I'm on a Mac?

Comment: This worked for me and it was the most readable.

Answer (score 0):

Some great answers above but I'll put mine just in case as well.

**This will just `echo` out the `mv` commands:**

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'for f do x=${f#./}; y="${x// /_}"; echo "mv ${x// /\ } ${y////-}"; done' {} +
```

**This will just `echo` out the `mv` commands into your pasteboard directly:**

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'for f do x=${f#./}; y="${x// /_}"; echo "mv ${x// /\ } ${y////-}"; done' {} + | pbcopy
```

**[Careful] This will immediately run the `mv` commands for you:**

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'for f do x=${f#./}; y="${x// /_}"; eval "mv ${x// /\ } ${y////-}"; done' {} +
```